# How to use "AND" in Entity Framework under the same column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have been looking for a way to retrieve some specific information from a table but it's nor retrieving any result, I am using Entity Framework and C#.

```
var plans = (
    from p in context.AirTables 
    where p.eflID == 536 && p.eflID == 537 
    select p)
    .ToList();
```

The `if (plans.Count() != 0)` is giving me 0 as value, and I am 100% sure that the information which I am retrieving is correct.

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Surely you need to OR (`||`) them together, not AND them together. 1 field can't have 2 values simultaneously!

Comment: Do you notice you are checking for equality for the same field against two different values? If it matches first condition it cannot match the second one and viceversa. A car can be red or green but not both colours at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are probably trying to retrieve the `AirTables` that cointain in the column `eflID` either `536` or `537` values. You could do it in several ways.

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 536, 537};
var plans = context.AirTables.Where(x=> ids.Contains(x.eflID)).ToList();
```

or

```
var plans = context.AirTables.Where(x=> x.eflID ==536 || x.eflID == 537).ToList();
```

the first one should translate into `... where eflID in (536, 537)` and the second one into `... where eflID=536 OR eflID = 537`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with `OR` and not `And`

```
var plans = context.AirTables.Where(x=> x.eflID ==536 || x.eflID == 537).ToList()
```